# How to solve an error "oTable.draw is not a function" in filtering datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables, filtering

I have a search form above the datatables. When I try to search, I have got the data shows in JSON format, not filtering the datatables. The error is

> Uncaught TypeError: oTable.draw is not a function

Here is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var oTable = $('#surat').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: '{!! route("surat") !!}',
            data: function (d) {
                d.jenis_surat = $('input[name=jenis_surat]').val();
                d.nomor_surat = $('input[name=nomor_surat]').val();
                d.perihal = $('input[name=perihal]').val();
            }
        },
        columns: [
            {data: 'no', name: 'no'},
            {data: 'jenis_surat', name: 'jenis_surat'},
            {data: 'nomor_surat', name: 'nomor_surat'},
            {data: 'perihal', name: 'perihal'},
            {data: 'status', name: 'status'}
        ]
    });

    $('#search_form').on('submit', function(e) {
        oTable.draw();
       e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
```

And this is the controller:

```
public function carisuratdata(Request $request)
{
    $surats = Surat::select(['id_surat', 'id_jenis_surat', 'nomor_surat','perihal', 'tanggal_surat', 'masa_berlaku_from', 'masa_berlaku_to', 'ringkasan', 'tag', 'id_publish', 'tanggal_publish'])->get();

    return Datatables::of($surats)
        ->filter(function ($instance) use ($request) {
            if ($request->has('jenis_surat')) {
                $instance->collection = $instance->collection->filter(function ($row) use ($request) {
                    return Str::contains($row['jenis_surat'], $request->get('jenis_surat')) ? true : false;
                });
            }

            if ($request->has('nomor_surat')) {
                $instance->collection = $instance->collection->filter(function ($row) use ($request) {
                    return Str::contains($row['nomor_surat'], $request->get('nomor_surat')) ? true : false;
                });
            }
            if ($request->has('perihal')) {
                $instance->collection = $instance->collection->filter(function ($row) use ($request) {
                    return Str::contains($row['perihal'], $request->get('perihal')) ? true : false;
                });
            }
        })

        ->make(true);

}
```

Here is the JSON:
[image]

Comment: try `oTable.ajax.reload()`

Answer (score 0):

Before you use the `draw`, it needs an action to call such as `search`, `order` etc. And `draw` is just to redraw the table and does not renew data from server side. After reviewing your code, your purpose is re-get the data from server side. Therefore, you need to use `oTable.ajax.reload();` to re-get the data from server.

For more infomation:

Ajax relaod:
https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()

Draw:
https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()

Comment: So I have to put `oTable.ajax.reload()` above `oTable.draw()` rght? I have did that but I still got the same result. Is it because I am using datatables 1.9 so I cant use draw() ? but when I am trying to use datatables 1.10 I have got an error `Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined`

Comment: use `oTable.ajax.reload()` to replace `oTable.draw()`

Comment: There are about 2 mistakes which may cause `Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined`. 1. your data columns number do not match you table columns number. 2. it does not return the format that it match the `DataTable` structure. so you may use chrome developer mode to watch that which problem that you are facing.

Comment: The output is still the same

Comment: can you provide your json which is for DataTable ??

Comment: I have updated the question. Or maybe you know the another way to make a datatables filtering form above the datatables box? This case drives me crazy.

Comment: do you try to print just `data` and just print what you need in json?

Comment: no. when I click my search filtering button, it shows json like in the picture above.

Comment: @hendraspt Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111382/discussion-between-user2352577l-and-hendraspt).